# How do I install Ubuntu on an ASUS C100P Chromebook

Tags: chromebook

The download file will not open because it's not supported. How do I open the ubuntu desktop file and install it?

Comment: Chromebook installation has a different [procedure](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343). In normal PCs, you have to burn the ISO image to a USB or DVD and boot from it. You can't just double-click and expect it'll install.

Answer (score -1):

First, activate developer mode for your Chromebook.

Next, check and see whether your laptop model is supported by [John Lewis'](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/) Seabios payload, which will allow you to boot an Ubuntu live USB after you run his script and choose one of the three options provided.

If you are able to run his script to rewrite the stock Chromebook BIOS, you will then be able to boot into the live USB drive and run the Ubuntu installer like you would from a DVD. Do note that these instructions carry the risk of bricking your device, but if you want to run Ubuntu on Chromebooks without further stability issues, you will want to explore this option.

Comment: Not on the C100P --- it's ARM based.

Answer (score -2):

**You need to burn the ISO to a DVD, and then boot the computer from that DVD**. (Normally a computer boots from the hard disk) If you're using Windows, you can burn the ISO with the included tool.

See: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-from-an-iso-file

Comment: While this is generally speaking a good answer, with Chromebooks it's not that simple.